# Spark dataframe creation with the schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an Array with name "test" as Array(col1, col2, col3).
And I have an RDD with data having for 3 fields as per col1,col2,col3 layout.

I want to read this RDD with the Array layout of col1, col2, col3 and create a dataframe for it in scala.

Can anyone please help on the same.

Comment: I know if I have a case class with column names I can associate this case class with the RDD and create a dataframe with it. Like below.

Comment: val DF = RDD.map(x=> caseclass_name(x.getString(0),x.getString(1),x.getString(2))).toDF()

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you have an `RDD[Array[(String, String, String)]]` that you want transformed to `RDD[(String, String, String)]` or do you have an `RDD[(String, String, String)]` where you just want to name the columns? Or ...??? Can you provide some code, so we can see what you are trying to do?